# How can I use react-planner in another react app?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I have installed react-planner in my react app and I want to use in react component. I follow the mentioned the guideline but not work in react component
**I tried that**

`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactPlanner from "react-planner";

function WarehouseDesign() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>design</h2>
      <ReactPlanner
        // catalog={MyCatalog}
        width={800}
        height={600}
        //  plugins={plugins}
        stateExtractor={(state) => state.get("react-planner")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default WarehouseDesign
```

;`

**ERROR**
Failed to compile
./src/components/dashboard/Warehouse/WarehouseDesign.tsx
Attempted import error: 'react-planner' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactPlanner').

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-planner
planner-link

Comment: change your import to `import  { ReactPlanner } from "react-planner";`